# "unexpected INDENT" in Rails Coffescript after Ruby version change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

### The Original Problem

Changed ruby version (`1.9.3` > `1.9.2`) and suddenly all coffeescripts started yielding `unexpected INDENT`.

I've triple-checked for *spaces/tabs* inconsistency on files, and this is not the issue. When I comment the entire script, the same bug jumps to the next/another coffeescript file.

Tried with `coffee-rails` versions 3.2.1 and 3.2.2. No success in both.

*Anyone to light a lamp?*

### More Details

I found what causing this, yet I can't understand why it shoud work differently for different Ruby versions. It's a long story, but here it goes.

I use a trick to declare *static* or *dynamic* getters and setters to my classes. This is something like:

```
Function::dynamic = (prop, desc) ->
  Object.defineProperty @prototype, prop, desc

Function::static = (prop, desc) ->
  Object.defineProperty @, prop, desc
```

This provides me a way to declare properties like this:

```
class MyClass
  @static 'accessor'
    get: -> _accessor
    set: (value) -> _acessor = value
```

I have *plenty of this* all over my code, but after Ruby downgrade the code structure just stopped working. Now I'll have to add **a comma** after the method's first parameter. Like:

```
@static 'accessor',
  get: -> (...)
```

And this is what it was all about. :S

Answer its not longer necessary, but if anyone could explain it... I'd be glad.

Comment: Just made it: First added, first called, first bugged. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax was not allowed "on purpose", if was merely allowed because the compiler refused to generate `'a'(...)`. `ID block` is a call

See [this issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2715).

Comment: Yeah, I see now. But... why the same `coffee-rails` gem would end up using different versions of the coffeescript compiler?

Comment: maybe you didn't locked your version carefully :)